# Fingerprint FMDs compatibility

Tags: c#, fingerprint, verification, biometrics, zkemkeeper

I'm designing a c# application for an access control turnstile with biometric verification. The turnstile uses the ZKTeco SF300 (IP) fingerprint scanner.

For registration (at a receptionist's desk a significant distance from the turnstile),  I want to use the Digital Persona UrU4500 (USB) to obtain fingerprints (either image or template/FMD - using their FingerJet SDK); just because it's cheaper than buying another SF300 unit. 
Then I'll extract_&_upload (if image) or just upload(if FMD) the template as FPtemplate for a new user struct into the SF300 & DB.

However, checking the ZKTeco ZKemKeeper API, I can't find any methods for extracting templates from images, so I can't use image.

I think both ZKTeco & CrossMatch templates/FMDs abide by the NIST biometric standards. Will that make their templates/FMDs compatible?

Or is there no escaping buying another SF300 unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative to buying another SF300 unit.

For avoiding troubleshooting with the templates and the algorithms, I recommend you to look for the [ZK9500](https://www.zkteco.com/en/product_detail/ZK9500.html) instead of the Digital Persona UrU4500 .

It doesn´t work directly with the zkemkeeper, but using it´s driver and API you can obtain the templates used by the zkemkeeper. **Don´t forget to check** that the SF300´s biokey version is compatible with this device and that you have configured it to use the same version that the ZK9500 (otherwise it won´t work). If it isn´t compatible, ask to your dealer in order to obtain a compatible model.

For programming questions on how to obtain the templates... Getting the template using this API It´s not a trivial task, but I think that they have available one demo with the source code, so you can take a look and extract the information you need in order to obtain the fingerprint templates.

Answer (score 0):

Already wasted my time on it before the answer was posted.
They're not compatible, and uploading the UrU4500 ANSI format FMDs to the SF300 resulted in buffer overflows. 
So even though there's an ANSI template option, I think the version is very important.

Comment: In spite of the fact that the ZKTeco devices may seem to use some specific format, my experience has proved me that they are not compatible with other brands... In fact, sometimes they are not even compatible with themselves.

Anyway... The ZK9500 should work with your device, It´s the latest version of this type of devices... Give it a shot, it should work as long as you are using Biokey 10.